# Nesting 3 different objects

Tags: javascript

```
    var a=[{"id":1,"total":1000},{"id":2,"total":2000}]
    var b=[{"id":1,"credit":500},{"id":2,"credit":1000}]
    var c=[{"id":1,"reversed":500},{"id":2,"amount":1000}]
```

I want something like this,

```
var newArray=[{"id":1,
                       "amount":
                         {"total":1000,"credit":500,"reversed":500}}
                       {"id":2,
                       "amount":
                         {"total":2000,"credit":1000,"reversed":1000}}
               ]
```

Is it possible to achieve this via a JavaScript function?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Take a stab at it. If you get stuck, post what you've tried, and we can help you with it.

Comment: Separately: That's not JSON. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON. Those are just JavaScript objects. Specifically, they're arrays with objects inside.

Comment: come on, what have you tried ? Of course it's possible. Try looping and let us know how you get on

Answer (score 0):

Try this way with [extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/)  and [each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

```js
    var a=[{"id":1,"total":1000},{"id":2,"total":2000}];
    var b=[{"id":1,"credit":500},{"id":2,"credit":1000}];
    var c=[{"id":1,"reversed":500},{"id":2,"amount":1000}];
    
    
    var result = $.extend(true, {}, a, b,c);
    
    var newArray = [];
    $.each(result,function(index,value){
      var ind = value.id;
      delete value['id']; //unset id here
      var amount = value;
      newArray.push({id: ind,amount:amount});
    });

    console.log(newArray);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hash table as reference to the objects with the same `id`. Iterate all arrays and with sub arrays take the keys and assign the value to the referenced object.

Method used:

- [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), to iterate the arrays
- [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), for getting all own keys of the object.

```js
var array1 = [{ "id": 1, "total": 1000 }, { "id": 2, "total": 2000 }],
    array2 = [{ "id": 1, "credit": 500 }, { "id": 2, "credit": 1000 }],
    array3 = [{ "id": 1, "reversed": 500 }, { "id": 2, "amount": 1000 }],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    result = [];

[array1, array2, array3].forEach(function (a) {
    a.forEach(function (o) {
        if (!hash[o.id]) {
            hash[o.id] = {};
            result.push(hash[o.id]);
        }
        Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
            hash[o.id][k] = o[k];
        });
    });
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```